# Parameterized delete confirmation Modal .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I'm little bit new in web development. I have an application with many Index sites which display list with elements. These elements are deletable with a HtmlAction. I want to make a generic? modal which appear when the user has clicked the button. This modal request a confirmation from user to delete the selected element from list. If I'm right I have to pass some data to this modal e.g. (which controller, which action, which elementId). Somehow can I create a parameterized modal? Can you give me some startpoint for this?

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="card">
        <table class="table">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h5>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => item.SupplyTypeName)</h5>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplyTypeName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <i class='material-icons'>
                            @Html.ActionLink("mode_edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
                        </i>
                        <i class='material-icons' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                            *
                        </i>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure want to delete this item?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without writing JavaScript you have to create own modal for every row. Also it's nice to show user something related to row in modal so user knows they clicked delete for correct row.

If you plan to use JavaScript then simplest is to add click event handler and show browsers own confirm popup with `confirm` function then cancel event if they don't click ok. Like `<a href="/delete/item/56" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>`

If you write JavaScript for Bootstrap modal you need add your own click event handler that gets data attributes of delete button and patches (maybe sets id for url where confirm button posts) modal using that data before showing it.

Comment: Thx I learned today some JavaScript too. It's work now. Thanks for the help.